# How can I use the output from mongodump to populate another database?

Tags: mongodb

I recently used `mongodump` to copy my production database named `app_production`. I copied the dump files to another machine, and I would like to use `mongorestore` to copy all the dump data into a database named `app_development`. How can I do this?

Comment: mongorestore --db app_development <path-to-dump-file>

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.